# FFprobe Check Stream Link

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, streaming, ffprobe

I am trying to use FFprobe to test if a streaming link is active or not.

For example this is a working streaming link:

```
ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_streams rtmp://Lrmh0w.cloud.influxis.com/yoy/_definst_/185
```

I do get output which mean link is active.

However, once I change link to something not work:

```
ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_streams rtmp://Lrmh0w.cloud.influxis.com/yoy/_definst_/18555555555
```

The command keeps running in background with no result.

Is there a way to bypass this, or is there any ffprobe timeout parameter?
I couldn't find it from the official website documentation.

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? @Krasic

Answer (score 6):

I'm just using *nix timeout:

```
/usr/bin/timeout 5s /usr/bin/ffprobe $SOURCE
```

In my case, it was enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-timeout n` before the url, where n is the number of seconds. If it doesn't help then you should ask the question without `-loglevel quiet`, including all the version info and error messages.

Comment: Hello avnr, didnt worked for me tried normal , without -loglevel quiet , timeout before/after url , before/after show_stream nothing...

Comment: The idea about removing -loglevel quiet is so that you can post the full dump and show all the info, such as ffprobe version, platform, included libs, the stream metadata, etc. You should re-post the question in a relevant forum such as superuser.com or SE's video production forum and include the full dump.

Comment: when i run without -loglevel quiet : it show ffprobe version, platform, included libs , however it stuck on stream medata and keep running on background with no result , is there any other way on php or ffprobe to check if a streaming link is up or down ?

Comment: If the dump includes metadata then it probably means that ffprobe was able to establish a connection. In RTMP the path portion of the URI is not really a path but the name of an application registered on the the media server. So - assuming ffprobe really shows metadata - this means that the media server accepted the connection, but hangs due to the application's absence; in other words this indicates a media server issue. It would be much more efficient to assist you if you were to post the dump, the information about the metadata for example is very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I will +1 on the answers above :
Adding a timeout before the ffprobe works.

```
ffprobe -show_format -timeout 1000000 -loglevel quiet  "${ChannelList[$i+1]}"
```

Would every now and then get stuck on a bad http request resulting in a 503 error (when looking at logs after removing loglevel quiet). Channel list is where all the stream links are loaded.

```
timeout 5s ffprobe -show_format -timeout 1000000 -loglevel quiet  "${ChannelList[$i+1]}"
```

This worked like a charm - prevented ffprobe from getting stuck indefinitely on a bad url and freezing the entire process.